# Document vs Collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with Firestore. The question is how to structure data, without running into a billing trap / nightmare.

I have following data structure:

```
school
  course1
    section1
      page1
      page2
    section2
      page1
      page2
    ...
```

I assume that a course usually would not have more than 50 sections.

**Use a collection**

So I could use a collection and create a document for each section that contains the name and description of each section.

```
db.collection("schools")
.document("school1")
.collection("courses")
.document("course1")
.collection("sections").snapshots()
```

Document Structure:

```
name: "Section 1"
description: "Description 1"
```

However if I need to display a list of the sections, then according to Firestore billing, I would get charged for each read of a document. Which means if there are 20 sections, I would get charged for 20 reads.

**Use a document with nested collections**

I could also just create a document "Course 1" and nest all the sections.

```
db.collection("schools")
.document("school1")
.collection("courses")
.document("course1")
.get()
```

Document Structure:

```
name: "Course 1"
description: "The description",
sections: [
  {
    name: "Section 1", 
    description: "Description 1"
    pages: [
      {name: "Page 1", description: "Page Description 1"},
      {name: "Page 2", description: "Page Description 2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Section 2", 
    description: "Description 2"},
    pages: [
      {name: "Page 1", description: "Page Description 1"},
      {name: "Page 2", description: "Page Description 2"}
    ]
  ...
]
```

Then I would only get charged for 1 read. Most likely I would not run into the 40'000 attributes limit and also not into the 1 MB limit.

But it looks like it takes some time to load the data from the document using FutureBuilder, which seems to be faster, if I get the documents in the collection with StreamBuilder.

So I somehow can't decide, which approach to take. It would somehow be more logical to use a collection because I will never run in any limits, and it seems faster to load, but from a billing point of view, it would make more sense, to nest the sections.

What option is the better one?

Comment: With NoSQL data modeling, the better option is the one that suits the needs of your app (which you haven't exactly specified).  You might be overthinking cost and performance.  Mostly, you should be thinking about how to organize data so that it can be queried usefully by your app, driven by your app's UI.  If you don't know what your UI and queries are going to be, then you are going to struggle with structuring your data.  Don't put the cart before the horse.

Comment: From a UI perspective, course, section and pages need to be loaded together. So one document would make more sense. I'm overthinking for sure, but I want to get it right from a cost perspective, as this could kill the whole case if I can't offer a competitive price to a customer. If I'm more expensive than the competition, the case is dead. If I trade in flexibility and need to move data, it might cause outages during a migration of data from documents into collections, and a lot of time and cost aswell. Guess I need to calculate in detail, if there are no technical vice versas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you that it is difficult when to choose a sub-collection approach over the conventional multiple collections approach. So please keep in mind the following cases when you decide to choose a sub-collections approach.

**When to use sub-collections:**

1) When you don't want to store a lot of fields in a document. Cloud Firestore has 20,000 field limit. (If the Schools and Courses information can exceed more than 20,000 fields)

2) When updating the parent collection is a common operation. Firestore only lets you update the document at rate of 1 write/second. (If the Schools,Courses and Pages information is modified very often)

3) When you want to limit the access to particular fields of a document. (If you want to restrict the access to a Course's Pages. In this case moving the restricted fields to another document in another collection is also a good idea!)

**When not to use sub-collections:**

1) When you want to query the collections and sub-collections together. Firestore queries are shallow. So sub-collections won't be queried when you query the parent collection so you have to query them separately. (If you have a case to show all the schools and their courses in one window)

2) When you want to show the sub-collection when viewing the collection.(When showing a school, you might want to show its courses. Here the number of reads will increase because instead of reading one document you are reading one document and its sub-collection all the time)

3) When you want to query collections and sub-collections together.(You have to use collection group query as sub-collections are essentially collections.)

4) If you're thinking about querying individual pieces of data, you should put them in a collection. (If the School's particular attributes are usually queried by users or a Course's details are looked upon by multiple users)

**My Suggestion:**

```
Schools
  - Array<CourseIds>
  - Other info
```

`Schools` collection to store school information on which schools can be searched according to their qualities. Schools information can also contain a field courses_available which can be an array or map to store the course name alone and its `unique id`.

```
Courses
  -Course info
```

`Courses` collection with the same approach since I'm assuming course information will be queried a lot according to their attributes.

```
CourseSections
  -Course1Section1
    -Pages
  -Course1Section2
    -Pages
```

`CourseSections` collection for info about the course sections which has a sub-collection 
 `Pages`.

Advantages:

1. This will help you to add a lot of pages to each section.
2. `CourseSection` can be read on demand, so that you don't need to read all of its sections while reading a `Course`.

Ultimately the choices depends on the use cases you have.

Hope this helps.